# Scenekit: Crash when Setting physicsBody to nil

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnnode

Can anyone help on this one:
Still coding on my game App in a tunnel cave, I installed moving walls within a not-moving frame.
The good thing is that I can move the walls within the parent nodes (the frames).
Bad thing is, I need to set a physicsBody physicsShape - for the frame a concavePolyhedron, while for the wall a boundingBox does the job.
Now, when I try to remove the walls, the scene crashes with a BAD_EXEC.
I tried a lot of different things to find out why, and as it turns out, the childNode walls seem to be the problem.
Because, even though it is possible to set the parent physicsBody to nil, the app crashes when I do the same thing with the childs (the walls). No matter if the nodes are hidden or not, and no SCNAction is attached.
I found a similar question, in which an answer was provided in C++, a command called ‚cleanUpChildrenAndRemove‘, but I am coding in Swift and there doesn‘t seem to be an analog.
I am pretty sure something is messed up, but I have no idea what it could be or how to straigthen it.
Does anyone have the same issue or know an answer?

Comment: Could you post portions of the relevant code you are using?

Comment: It‘s a bit complicated, but I will try to.

Comment: The Problem has just gotten much more difficult: in the app, I have an editor mode and the gaming mode. Whereas in the editor all nodes are shown, only those visible to the player are unhidden in the game mode in order to save GPU capacity. So, in the game mode, there is a lot of hiding/unhiding. When I was using the identical routine for the physicsShapes (my original question) the editor worked fine and the game crashed. So I guess the Problem really is the node-modification at the wrong time. Can you post a link where the modification via the renderer delegate is described?

Comment: I really dont understand your issue without more code details. But in general: Setting an active Physics-Body to nil is not such a good idea. I also wanted to do this, but ended up in modifying the Bitmasks to kind of Dummy-Bitmasks instead of niling them - because of the crashes.

Comment: Hi Zay, actually I set it to nil because just removing it was the original reason for the crash. Because actually, the target is to remove the nodes.

Comment: I found the bug. The reason for the crashing was that I hid the node at some other point. Although I prepared for that by unhiding all nodes before removing them, this seemingly wasn‘t sufficient. Now it‘s all working. But thanks for your efforts.